# Conflict between colorbox and bootstrap libs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, colorbox

There is a conflict between using [ColorBox iFrame](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) with the [Bootstrap, from Twitter](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) ..
I am trying to use the following coee to resolve the conflict ,, but the same problem :

including the required libs:

```
<script src="../jq/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="../js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

color box js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

      // colorbox code here 
        });
```

and bootstrap js:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

      // bootstrap twitter code here 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Both functions do the same as long as `jQuery === $` in the current scope (which is usually the case).

The first version is better though as it also works if `noConflict` was used.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // both colorbox and bootstrap code here 
});
```